# Does Hive support temporary view?

Tags: hive

I am reading https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateView,

I would ask whether Hive supports to create temporary view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not, by today it only supports temporary tables.

Comment: Thanks @hlagos for the helpful answer